# Identityserver4 not redirecting to xamarin.forms android app after login

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, identityserver4

I've been working my head around this issue for a few days now, but I can't figure out what the problem is.
I'm implementing Identityserver4 and got this up and running with the following client configuration;

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(string somesecret)
            {
                return new List<Client> {
                    new Client {
                            ClientId = "xamarin.app",
                            ClientName = "Xamarin Mobile App.",
                            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt, //default
                            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {new Secret(somesecret.Sha256())}, 
                            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                            {
                                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                                //"xamarin.app",
                            },
                            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                            RequireConsent = false,
                            RequirePkce = true,
                            RequireClientSecret = false,
                            RedirectUris = new List<string>{ "https://localhost:44310/grants", "https://some-idp-server.net/grants", "com.xamarin.app:/oauth2redirect"}
                    }
                };
            }
```

All the code I'm using at the moment is based on the exapmles on the following sites;

- https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4
- https://sinclairinat0r.com/2018/12/09/secure-data-access-with-identityserver4-and-xamarin-forms
- https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2018/12/11/identity-server-4-with-asp-net-core-2-2/

So far everything looks good from my perspective and everything works. When I locally run the Identityserver I can login, my account is properly validated and I'm being redirected to the homepage of the identityserver.

Now my xamarin app is using the following piece of code to connect to the identityserver. This also works, because when the code is triggered, I'm being presented with the login-screen from my Identityserver.

```
var oAuth = new OAuth2AuthenticatorEx("xamarin.app"
                                    , "openid profile"
                                    , new Uri("https://some-idp-server.net/connect/authorize")
                                    //, new Uri("https://some-idp-server.net/grants")
                                    , new Uri("com.xamarin.app:/oauth2redirect")
                                    , isUsingNativeUI:false)
            {
                AccessTokenUrl = new Uri("https://some-idp-server.net/connect/token"),
                ShouldEncounterOnPageLoading = false
            };

            var account = Task.Run(async () => await App.GetCurrentUserAccountAsync("oAuth")).ConfigureAwait(false)
                                                    .GetAwaiter()
                                                    .GetResult();

            if (account != null)
            {
                App.AuthAccount = account;
                App.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {account.Properties["access_token"]}");

                OAuthLoginPage.LoginSuccess(null);
            }
            else
            {
                oAuth.Completed += Presenter_Completed;
                oAuth.Error += Presenter_Error;

                var presenter = new OAuthLoginPresenter();
                presenter.Completed += Presenter_Completed;
                presenter.Login(oAuth);
            }
```

But the problem lies after logging in. Instead of being redirected to the app, I'm seeing a blank page and nothing seems to be happening. This seems to be some sort of default behavior of Identityserver4, because when running locally I see the default page with versionnumber etc.. But when deployed, I also see a white page with a 404 responsecode when browsing https://some-idp-server.net directly. So I suspect that identityserver is pretending not to be there for securityreasons, which makes sense.

Now as far as my knowledge goes regarding the Identityserver, and I'm quite new to this topic, the actual issue has to do with the redirecturl. Researching the internet also pushed my in this direction, and that actually made me add 'com.xamarin.app:/oauth2redirect' as redirect url to the client on the identityserver. However, still no luck. Can anybody help me out on this?

Perhaps it's good to know that this is being called from a pagerenderer after a button click. But I'm not seeking the problem here, since I'm getting the loginscreen as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling Application Insights on Azure I was able to see the issue. Apperently not all the migrations were properly executed. This caused the issue because a required table was not available in the database.